# Java mongo-spark-connector - How to write UnOrdered bulk writes into MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

Can anybody help me in writing *Unordered* bulk documents into MongoDB from Java using mongo-spark-connector?

Below is my spark & mongo configuration:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried writing bulk documents but all inserts are happening with ordered: true.

```
 Map<String, String> writeOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
        writeOverrides.put("collection", collection);
        writeOverrides.put("maxBatchSize", 1000);
        writeOverrides.put("writeConcern.w", "1");        
        writeOverrides.put("forceInsert", "true");
        writeOverrides.put("ordered", "false");//For Unordered inserts
WriteConfig wc = WriteConfig.create(SparkMongoSession.sparkContext).withOptions(writeOverrides);
MongoSpark.save(dataSet, wc);
```

Mongo Log:

```
[conn173] command MyDB.MyCollection command: insert { insert: "MyCollection", **ordered: true**, writeConcern: { w: 1 }, $db: "MyDB" } **ninserted:1000** keysInserted:1000 ....
```